# Ошибка при создании таблицы dash со столбцом, содержащим кнопки со ссылками для загрузки файла

Tags: python, dash

у меня создано приложение dash, в котором необходимо добавить вкладку с таблицей. в этом проблемы нет. проблема заключается в том, что я могу создать таблицу с данными типа: int, str, bool. однако у меня есть столбец со ссылкой, для которой нужно создать дополнительный столбец с кнопкой для скачивания(загрузки) лог файла по этой ссылке. вот мой код:

```
data = {'Time': dates, 'Strategy': strategies, 'Job': jobs, 'Status': statuses, 'Link to log': logs}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
def render_download_link(link):
    return html.A('Download log', href=link, target='_blank')
df['Download_log'] = df['Link to log'].apply(render_download_link)
layout = html.Div([
    dash_table.DataTable(
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        columns=[
            {'name': 'Time', 'id': 'Time'},
            {'name': 'Strategy', 'id': 'Strategy'},
            {'name': 'Job', 'id': 'Job'},
            {'name': 'Status', 'id': 'Status'},
            {'name': 'Link to log', 'id': 'Link'},
            {'name': '', 'id': 'Download_log', 'presentation': 'markdown'}
        ],
        style_data_conditional=[
                {
                    'if': {'column_id': 'Download_log'},
                    'textAlign': 'center'
                }
            ]
    )
])
```

однако при загрузке приложения, выводится ошибка неверного формата данных и приложение не работает. подскажите пожалуйста, какие есть варианты. спасибо